# a claim about extension of field

Tags: extension-field

Let A⊂B be rings,with B integral over A and B is finitely generated over A.  Let P be a prime ideal of B and p be a prime ideal of A such that p＝P∩A , then B/P is an extension of A/p of finite degree.

I can't think of how to proof this claim. Why is ［B/P:A/p］finite?

Answer (score 1):

integral + finitely generated (as an algebra) = finite (as a module), i.e. $B$ is a finite $A$-module. Let $b_1, \dotsc, b_n$ be generators. Then the residue classes $\overline b_1, \dotsc, \overline b_n$ are generators of the $A/p$-vector space $B/P$.

---

Note the following: Even is $B$ is $A$-free and $b_1, \dotsc, b_s$ a basis, the residue classes might be not linear independent.

For example take $\mathbb Z \subset \mathbb Z[i]$ with basis $1,i$ and take $P=(1-i) \subset \mathbb Z[i]$. The residue classes $\overline 1$ and $\overline i$ are equal in $\mathbb Z[i]/(1-i)$. The field extension $\mathbb F_2 = \mathbb Z/(P\cap A) \subset \mathbb Z[i]/(1-i) = \mathbb F_2$ is of degree $1$, while the free module was of rank $2$.

Comment: thank you, but I can't proof  \overline{b_1},...,\overline{b_n} are independent over A/p. Although l've proofed any element of B/P can be written by linear combination of overline{b_1},...,\overline{b_n} over A/p...

Comment: I never claimed that they should be independent, they do not have to be. They are just finitely many generators.

Comment: I misunderstood...  Thank you, I've completely understood!!

Comment: I added an example where an $A$-basis of $B$ does not give you an $A/p$-basis of $B/P$. So in general, they are really only generators. You cannot expect them to be a basis.

Comment: I see. They are not independent generelly...  I appriciate it.